# Mongoid Query Related Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to figure out how to query related collections in Mongoid.

Here is my object model (simplified for brevity):

```
Category
-------------------
class Category
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String
    ...
    belongs_to: product
end

class Product
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, type: String
   ...
   has_one :category
end
```

I'm trying to build a query to get all products with category with a particular name e.g. "Toy"

```
products = Product.where('category.name' => 'Toy')
```

I get a nil collection back. I think mongoid does not support this types of queries directly. How do I build a query that will accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
category = Category.find_by(name: 'Toy')
# all the following will work
products = Product.where(category: category)
products = Product.where(category_id: category.id)
```

this will work, [but it's not recommended to use mongoid this way](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html#relational_associations)

> Mongoid provides relational-style associations as a convenience for application developers who are used to dealing with relational databases, but we do not recommend you use these extensively.

Comment: Yes, I had a feeling that this may not be a good mongoid way of doing things. I think I'm going to have an array field for each category in product. However, I still would like to have a separate collection with a list of categories so I can easily display a category list (with extra information). That will lead to two models without any associations. Would that be a better design? I do realize that I will need to enforce data integrity in the application layer in this case, but changes to category names are very rare.

Comment: no you got me wrong... your scenario is perfectly right and correct... and my answer on how you get the data... is correct... the not recommended comment is about using mongodb as relational database... if you have enough time to read [this article](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/) please do... cause you will understand the nosql databases and it's limitations.... the quote should be... **It's not recommended to use mongodb/mongoid as relational database**